# How is the reference count from "function argument" different from that from "Python's function stack" - Python

Tags: python, reference-counting

I am trying to understand the reference count in Python.  Here is an example I got from the post (https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/):

```
foo = []

# 2 references, 1 from the foo var and 1 from getrefcount
print(sys.getrefcount(foo))

def bar(a):
    # 4 references
    # from the foo var, function argument, getrefcount and Python's function stack
    print(sys.getrefcount(a))

bar(foo)
# 2 references, the function scope is destroyed
print(sys.getrefcount(foo))
```

I am not clear about why the second `sys.getrefCount` is 4.  The writer said the four references are from the foo var, function argument, getrefcount and Python's function stack.  Isn't the reference from calling the `bar(foo)` the same as `Python's function stack`?  Can someone explain in details? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- foo is one reference pointer to that empty list
- bar(foo)--> here foo is another variable referring to the same empty list
- def bar(a) --> here a is another variable referring to the same empty list
- Inside bar function, sys.getrefcount(a) --> creates one temporary reference to the same empty list
- Hence totally it is 4